# Collapsing of forwarding references

Tags: c++, c++20

Given the code

```
struct S{};

template <typename T>
auto foo(T&& t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>);
}

void test()
{
    const S s;
    foo(s);  // error

    foo(S{});

    S s2;
    foo(s2); // error
}
```

`T` will be deduced as

1. `S const&`
2. `S`
3. `S&`

Why is `T` not deduced as

1. `S const`
2. `S`
3. `S`

Why does `T` keep the reference in the lvalue cases and not in the rvalue case?

[playground](https://godbolt.org/z/pHZqsZ)

Comment: Because the standard says so.

Comment: @Ayxan that is rarely an answer. Usually one wants to know **why** the standard says so.

Comment: In that case that person should read the Rationale for the
International Standard

Comment: @Ayxan if anyone would do that, and if anyone would fully understand the standard, we wouldn't need a Q&A platform.

Comment: @Ayxan There is no "Rationale for the International Standard." There is a long series of proposal papers (thousands of them), but even those don't necessarily cover the full rationale...

Comment: @Barry There seems to be [one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) for the C language, but not C++. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) works in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_function_call):

(emphasis mine)

> 4) If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, **the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of `std::forward`**

That means, if an lvalue is passed, `T` will be deduced as lvalue-reference. Otherwise, if `T` would be deduced as the same type for both lvalue and rvalue in a forwarding reference, [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) could not be used to perform perfect forwarding again; i.e. forwarding as lvalue when an lvalue is passed and forwarding as rvalue when an rvalue is passed.

Answer (score 3):

One of the quirks of forwarding references is that you never have "just a value".

When `T` is deduced as `S`, this is only because the function is actually accepting `S&&`.

When you pass your local variables, type deduction recognizes that these are lvalues, and so it binds them to regular references. A `const` one in the case of `const S s`. The function signature "changes" to reflect that.

You'll have `(const S&)&&`, which the standard dicates collapses to just `const S&`, and then you'll have `(S&)&&` which collapses to just `S&`, per the rules for reference collapsing.

Refer to [[dcl.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#6)

### [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/nJ9WM5) (Live demo)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand how reference collapsing works. Turns out I had a missunderstanding of what exactly a forwarding reference is.